# Washed out syntax highlighting colors in VSCode

Tags: 19.10, colors, color-management, visual-studio-code

I have just installed Ubuntu 19.10 (coming from Win10) and have installed my preferred code editor VSCode - but noticed immediately that the color schemes are off: they are pale/washed out and nearly unusable for syntax highlighting. 
I have found two proposed solutions that seemed to have worked for people in the past, but neither worked for me:

1. Starting VSCode from the terminal with a flag to force the use of sRGB color profile: `code --force-color-profile=srgb`. This starts VSCode while returning `Option "force-color-profile" is unknown. Ignoring.`, and without any change to the washed out colors.
2. Adding `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('force-color-profile', 'srgb');` to the `main.js` file in the VSCode app folder. I tried that too, but nothing changed. I might have tried adding at the line the wrong place though, as I am unfamiliar with JS (I tried several options that seemed plausible).

I found these fixes on GitHub (e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/65816) - where they also reported this issue fixed with the update to Electron 6. I'm using VSCode v1.41.1, which uses Electron 6.1.5.

Any help for where I could look next would be helpful!